# ctypes Fixed-size char Array in Structure Field and Initialization

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, ctypes

How do I initialize a fixed-size character array, such as `char a[32]`, field of a structure using `ctypes`? Example:

```
import ctypes

class MyStructure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", ctypes.c_char * 32)]

a = (ctypes.c_char * 32)(*b"Hi!")
mystruct = MyStructure(a=a)
```

This gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line ..., in <module>
    mystruct = MyStructure(a=a)
TypeError: expected bytes, c_char_Array_32 found
```

Additional info: this is a MWE of a C++ DLL that has a structure with fixed-size character arrays that act as strings (e.g., names of things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a byte string as the error message suggests.  `ctypes` will complain if it is too long:

```
import ctypes

class MyStructure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", ctypes.c_char * 32)]

mystruct = MyStructure(b'Hi')
print(mystruct.a)
mystruct = MyStructure(b'Hi'*16)
print(mystruct.a)
mystruct = MyStructure(b'Hi'*17)
print(mystruct.a)
```

Result:

```
b'Hi'
b'HiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec(codeObject, __main__.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\metolone\Desktop\x.py", line 10, in <module>
    mystruct = MyStructure(b'Hi'*17)
ValueError: bytes too long (34, maximum length 32)
```

Comment: Funny... I thought I had to initialize variables with their respective `ctypes` or `ctypes.wintypes` constructors. For example, there's a `ctypes.int` field, and it works if I either initialize it as `b = 123` or `b = ctypes.int(123)`.

Comment: Since type is declared in the structure (or `.argtypes`, for functions) Python knows the type and constructs it for you.